# Executing another MySQL statement while inside an open DataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

I have WPF application that uses MySQL connection to work with the database. I have a specific query that checks whether my input information has a unique id that already exists in the database. If it does, then I need to do nothing but if it doesn't I need to insert a new record there.
Below is the code that I have. The problem is that inside the last using statement where I try to create and execute a new command, I get an error saying "Already an open DataReader exists with this connection."

By the looks of it, I need to establish a different connection and use that instead but is there a work around using the current connection instead?

```
 using (MySqlCommand checkCmd = con.CreateCommand())
 {
     checkCmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = @RFID";
     checkCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RFID", myValue);

     using (MySqlDataReader reader = checkCmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         //if not found, then insert the new value in the database
         if (!reader.Read())
         {
              using (MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
              {
                  //try to create and execute insert query here
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the existing connection `con`, and don't create another `cmd`?

Comment: Try using dataset/dataadapter (OR) create a procedure which will do all this task at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample, you could simply close the reader and do the insert;

```
bool found;

using (MySqlCommand checkCmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    checkCmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = @RFID";
    checkCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RFID", myValue);

    using (MySqlDataReader reader = checkCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        found = reader.Read();
    }
}

if(!found) {
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        //try to create and execute insert query here
    }
}
```

Another possible option if `id` is supposed to be unique is to not do the select at all, just set a unique index on `id` and use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert the row if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be create a procedure which will do all this task at once like

```
create procedure insertifnotexist @rfid int,@someothercolumn varchar(10)
as
begin
declare @tabid int;
SELECT @tabid = id FROM table WHERE id = @rfid;
if(@tabid = '')
insert into table values(@rfid,@someothercolumn);
end
```

Then from your code call this procedure passing the @RFID parameter.